# Ending a document in r Markdown and continuing with code

Tags: r, markdown, document

I am writing a report using r markdown. However, after this report is produced I would like to continue to analyse the data without having to open up a new editor window.
I was wondering if there is a simple command I could use to express the end of the document?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are not necessarily interested in *ending* your markdown document but in hiding your results. The code below will enable you to continue the analysis in the same window and to exclude it from appearing in the core document when compiled.

````
```{r results='hide', message=FALSE, warning=FALSE} 
# Stuff that you want to do
```
````

For a more detailed explanation, you may want to have a look at the [Chunk Options](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/) in the `knitr` documentation.